# \RequirePackage without option clashes because of the package loading order?

Tags: color, incompatibility, package-writing, package-options, option-clash

I am writing a package which requires the `xcolor` package with `table` option.
It is loaded in the package with

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
```

which works if my package is loaded after the user loaded `xcolor` itself. However if my package is loaded before the user loads `xcolor`, the user gets an option clash.

I can not load `xcolor` at the beginning of the document. In that case more or less the whole package can only be loaded at the beginning of the document.

How can/should this be solved?

Comment: If your package is loaded after **xcolor** the `table` option will *not* be passed to **xcolor**.

Comment: Are you sure it works if the user load xcolor before your package? I would have expected the table-option to be ignored in this case.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer in your question that you're talking about _writing_ a package, in order to make it more helpful and more findable for other users; hope that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
```

instead. `xcolor` does the same with the option `table`

Comment: what happens if the user loaded colortlb after xcolor? Then both of my commands will be ignored, but xcolor does not know colortlb was loaded, or am I wrong?

Comment: As I alread wrote, `xcolor` does nothing else than a `RequirePackage{colortbl}`. It is not important when `colortbl` is loaded, by the user or by your package

Comment: According to the documentation colortbl should not be loaded after xcolor. So you should use `\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}`. This can give option clash errors, but all other possibilies mean that your user can load the package(s) in the wrong order without getting any warning.

Comment: The reason why I load it explicitely before xcolor and do not need the optional argument. If a user loads both the other way round before, then there is already no chance to change the behaviour

Comment: @Herbert. But 1. What if the user loads only `xcolor`? And 2. `xcolor`contains a `\@ifXCopt{table}...` code, which means that part of the code is only executed if the `table` option is used (e.g. `\rowcolors` (with s) is defined there).

Comment: that is the situation I already mentioned

Comment: ? I'm not getting it. Above you make the impression that loading `colortbl` and `xcolor` independently is the same that using the option `table`. But this is simply not true. `\rowcolors` is only defined if you use `table`. Also it is still unclear if the loading order `xcolor` (by user) `colortbl` (by package) gives the same result than `colortbl` `xcolor` (both by package).