# Problem with dtx code: rowcolors unknown

Tags: tables, color, dtx

I get the following error in my `.dtx` file:

```
) (./test.dtx
! Undefined control sequence.
l.35 % \rowcolors
{1}{colorrow}{colorbody}
```

which I do not understand since `xcolor` and `colortbl` are loaded and all other `xcolor` commands work.

This is the code of the `.dtx` file for testing:

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{test.dtx}
%</driver>
%<package>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
%<package>\ProvidesPackage{test}
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{test}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
%
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%
\listfiles
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
  \PrintChanges
  \PrintIndex
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \GetFileInfo{test.dtx}
%
% \colorlet{colorbody}{white!100}
% \colorlet{colorsubhead}{gray!30}
% \colorlet{colorhead}{gray!25}
% \colorlet{colorrow}{gray!15.0}
%
% \rowcolors{1}{colorrow}{colorbody}
% \begin{tabular}{*{2}{p{0.45\textwidth}}}
%  content  & content \tabularnewline
%  content  & content \tabularnewline
%  content  & content \tabularnewline
% \end{tabular}
% 
% \StopEventually{}
% \clearpage
% \section{Implementation}
%
% \iffalse
%<*test.sty>
% \fi
%
% \subsection{Setup and packages}           
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{test}
%    \end{macrocode}
% 
%    \begin{macrocode}
\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{colortbl} 
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse
%</test.sty>
% \fi
%
% \Finale
\endinput
```

Comment: Read my comments in your previous question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/requirepackage-without-option-clashes-because-of-the-package-loading-order. You must use the [table]-Option when loading xcolor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace

```
\RequirePackage{colortbl}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
```

at line 16+17 by

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

because package loading at the document preamble should be done using `\usepackage` instead of `\RequirePackage`, and at line 59+60 by

```
\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}
```

because loading both packages on your own is not the same. Section 2.12, "*Color in table*", of [xcolor](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) manual recommends using the option because:

> These commands require the table option.

"These commands" are `\rowcolors`, `\rowcolors*`, `\showrowcolors`, `\hiderowcolors`, and `\rownum` (which is not a command but a TeX counter).

Comment: The reason why I load them separately is shown here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/requirepackage-without-option-clashes-because-of-the-package-loading-order.
If I load the package with options I risk option clash problems.

Comment: Nevertheless it is better, that the user gets information about a problem instead of having a problem without information. I'd add something like `\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{\@ifundefined{\rowcolors}{\PackageError{test}{xcolor must not be loaded before test without option table}{You've already …}}{}}{}` before `\RequirePackage[table]{xcolor}` at test.sty, to give the user more information about the problem and to suggest a solution.

Comment: I do that already.