# Option clash with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, packages, arxiv, option-clash

If anyone has come across this issue when dealing with uploading tex files on arxiv, their experience would be of immense help:

I am trying to upload a `.tex` document to arxiv. I upload my .tex file and my .eps figures and .bbl as requested.

When I process my files **no pages of output** are produced because of an

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.`

Now, how do I deal with this? How exactly/with what package must I use `\PassOptionsToPackage{...}` or `\RequirePackage{...}` as done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35156/11134)?

**My preamble is:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib} % enhances bibtex citations
\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Useful for file names with underscores in them
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{grffile}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}} %To highlight text
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}} %For footnotes
```

**Log file generated by arxiv** is available here on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Y2ww9ttQ)

## EDIT:

I edited my latex file and **removed** `\usepackage{hyperref}`. This definitely got rid of the `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.` message *but* now the **arXiv** TeX compiler gives me a fatal error **after** several `package natbib warning`s for all the references.

Do I have a problem with `natbib` only?

Comment: your shown code can't produce this kind of error message. Create a _complete_ example, which shows the error.

Comment: @Herbert That is the problem. when I run latex on my .tex file: no errors, no grief! However when I upload my latex file to `arxiv`: all kinds of errors! Will try to put together a minimum working example but I daresay this might be an arxiv related issue.

Comment: @drN: Then do _not_ load hyperref. I suppose it is done by the documentclass or something else.

Comment: @Herbert Yes. I am modifying my document to work without hyperref. Lets see what transpires!

Comment: drN, if you have found an answer to your question then by all means post it as an answer!

Comment: @drN yes as Scott said, please remove the solution from the question and post an answer (and accept it)

Answer (score 11):

I had to contact the folks at arXiv and they asked me to include `authblk.sty
setspace.sty, subfig.sty, caption.sty, caption2.sty, caption3.sty, babel.sty` with my .tex document and eps figures and .bbl file.

Apparently these style files are the only packages that might be mixed versions from what we're running in our environment.

This sorted everything out and I have a submission on arXiv now!

Comment: Where do I find all these style files?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi On Linux, you can use `locate caption.sty` to find `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty`.

Comment: setspace.sty did it for me.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same problem but the solution was entirely different.

Initially, the arXiv submission failed. I did a search for "error" and found the phrase "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref." so I thought this was the cause.

But, it turned out that the submission failed because of an unrelated problem - I forgot to upload one of the graphic files. Once I uploaded that file, I got a message saying "Submission processed OK". I still see the error message "! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.", but the PDF is created OK and I can proceed with the submission to arXiv.

Comment: This just happened to me again. I got the "Option clash for package hyperref" error, but the real error was related to natbib.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide this answer. The same issue. Forgot a pic. Same cryptic error.

Comment: thanks, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was using `acmart.cls` and had the `review` option enabled:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,review]{acmart}
```

Removed `review`, and arxiv was happy:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since the OP uses the document class `article` that does not know about option `review`, I have doubts that this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after removing `natbib` got resolved.  Clearly, this solution won't work for papers that need to use `natbib`.

Comment: I realized that I did not need `natbib` in my article.  I removed it and arXiv was able to process my files.  As I say in the answer, this will not work for everyone, but since it resolved my problem, there is a chance that it may resolve others' too.