# How to decypher Arxiv latex compilation errors

Tags: arxiv

I am trying to make my first submission to arXiv. I have a document with multiple include modules and images. When arXiv compiles it, it throws a lot of output, the major error being:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'nameinlink' for package 'cleveref'.
```

Needless to say that the document compiles no problem on my machine.

I will write the document preamble here, perhaps it is of any help

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[sort&compress,super]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, esint}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{url}  
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usepackage[overlay,absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{0.122, 0.435, 0.698}
```

Please help

**EDIT**

Removing `[nameinlink]` from `cleveref` brings me one step further:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.107 \begin
{document}
?
! Emergency stop.
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Sorry, I forgot the  mdframed in the original post

Comment: typically it's just because they have an old tex distribution and presumably the cleverref package didn't have that option then, simplest if you do not need it is simply to remove `[nameinlink]`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Please give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077).

Comment: Hey strpeter, I am afraid that a minimal working example will require me two hours of uploading different files to arxiv system, sorry

Comment: that's odd in the code you show you only load hyperref once and with no options, the `h` text of that message shows exactly which option is clashing I'm not sure if you can get that back from arxiv? otherwise perhaps there system adds hyperref in which case you could simply comment out your `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to add one more thing into preamble, I think it is the one causing the problem

Comment: I've had exactly this problem with several arXiv submissions, and I'm pretty sure it's because (as David Carlisle speculates) they have an outdated version of cleveref.  The simplest solution is to include an up-to-date cleveref.sty as one of the files in your submission.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution here.

[Option clash with hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118687/option-clash-with-hyperref/284400#284400)

The answer is to completely ignore hyperref errors and ensure that all of the other errors - e.g. missing pictures are in place. If the above error is the only error in the document, it compiles nevertheless

Comment: You might also find [the list of package loaded by default by ArXiv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347080/34551) of some interest to debug their error message.